# Can't do blocking read from named pipe (FIFO) in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ipc, named-pipes

It is very weird that I can't seem to make this work. This is my architecture: I have a named pipe which will communicate between a *always-running* `root` reader process and multiple application writer processes. The reader process has to be `blocking` while the writers are `nonblocking`. Therefore this is what I do in the reader process which will run with `root` privilege.

**reader.c**

```
#define PIPE_ID "/dev/shm/mypipe"
// This function configures named pipe
void configure_pipe() {
  // So that others can write
  umask(0000);
  if(mkfifo(PIPE_ID, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWGRP
        | S_IWOTH) != 0) {
    perror("mkfifo error\n");
  }
}
```

In main function:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int Process_Pipe_ID;
  configure_pipe();

  // main loop which never ends
  while(1) {
    if((Process_Pipe_ID = open(PIPE_ID, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
      perror("pipe file open error\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
    int bytes_read = 0;
    Message_Struct_t msg;

    // loop to keep reading from the pipe if there are messages to be read
    while((bytes_read = read(Process_Pipe_ID, &msg, sizeof(Message_Struct_t))) != 0) {
      if(bytes_read < 0) {
        perror("Pipe reading error in Scheduling agent\n");
        exit(-1);
      }
      printf("Read: %d, first: %d, second: %d\n", bytes_read, msg.first, msg.second);
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    close(Process_Pipe_ID);
  }
}
```

I expect this reader to be not blocked on `open` but it should keep reading from the named pipe if there's something on the pipe. Then, if it receives `0` which means `EOF` (nothing available in pipe) then it should close the file descriptor and open it again to keep trying reads from the pipe. It is kinda [busy-waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

I expect the `bytes_read` to be exactly the `sizeof(Message_Struct_t)` (24 bytes) because I setup my writer as atomic. 24 bytes is less than `PIPE_BUF`, therefore [Linux assures](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) that it is atomic as long as I don't exceed the size-limit of a pipe. I am no way exceeding the size-limit. My writer `programs` are like clients; they come, execute and terminate. So the writing side of the pipe is not always `open`. This is my very simple writer:

**writer.c**

```
void writeInts(int first, int second) {
  Process_Pipe_ID = open(PIPE_ID, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
  Message_Struct_t msg;
  msg.first = first;
  msg.second = second;
  int num;
  if((num = write(Process_Pipe_ID, &msg, sizeof(msg))) < 0) {
    perror("Error in writing\n");
    exit(-1);
  }  else
    printf("%d bytes wrote to pipe.\n", num);
  close(Process_Pipe_ID);
}
```

However, I am getting very weird output. I don't get anything on screen (for the `reader.c`) until I press `enter`. When I press enter I get the following:

```
Read: 1, first: 0, second: 0
Read: 1, first: 0, second: 0
Read: 1, first: 0, second: 0
```

When I press some other key and then `enter`, I get this:

```
Read: 1, first: 0, second: 0
aa
Read: 3, first: 0, second: 0
aaa
Read: 4, first: 0, second: 0
```

I have no idea what really is happening and how to go about this. I want to have a blocking read while the writers are non-blocking and atomic. I have searched a lot and then written the code but it is very weird that I can't get it to work.

Comment: try not to use `nonblock` mode, it helps to catch the deadlock.

Comment: open pipe outside of the loop. I don't know that trying open pipe more than one times whether it is UB or another error if the pipe is already opened,

Comment: Why? The `read` says that it will return `0` in case there's end of file.

Comment: I have tried not using `nonblocking` mode, the behavior doesn't change.

Comment: Sounds like `Process_Pipe_ID` is somehow getting set to 0, 1 or 2 (which is the terminal). Are any other functions accessing `Process_Pipe_ID`? Are you sure you haven't typed == somewhere instead of = or vice versa? Maybe print out `Process_Pipe_ID` before reading to check.

Comment: what is the definition of: `Message_Struct_t`

Comment: from: `man 3 mkfifo`  "it  has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can
       proceed to do any input or output operations on it."  Strongly suggest deleting the FIFO node before trying to create it.  Otherwise, if it already exists (say from a prior run of the program) then the call to `mkfifo()` will fail

Comment: in file: `reader.c`  only open the FIFO once, only close it once.  I.E. move the calls to `open()` and `close()` out of the `while()` loop

Comment: the code in `configure_pipe()` probably should check for the existence of the FIFO (perhaps via `stat()` before trying to create it.

Comment: before executing: `printf("Read: %d, first: %d, second: %d\n", bytes_read, msg.first, msg.second);`  be sure to check that the total number of bytes read is equal to: `sizeof( Message_struct_t )`  If not, the use a 'sliding window' in a loop to read more bytes (for a FIFO, usually reading just one byte at a time greatly simplifies the error checking)

Comment: in `writer.c`, regarding: `if((num = write(Process_Pipe_ID, &msg, sizeof(msg))) < 0) {`  always check that `sizeof( Message_struct_t )` bytes were written and if not, then loop until they are all written

Comment: in `writer.c`, regarding: `Process_Pipe_ID = open(PIPE_ID, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);`  1) remove the `O_NONBLOCK`  2) check that the returned value from `open()` indicates the call was successful before trying to write to the FIFO

Comment: Strongly suggest removing all references to `O_NONBLOCK`

Comment: regarding: `#define PIPE_ID /dev/shm/mypipe`  creating files in `/dev/' usually requires 'root' permission.  Much better to use some publicly accessible directory like `/tmp`

Comment: You're clearly missing quotes around the value of the `PIPE_ID` macro — the code wouldn't compile as shown.  What else is different between the code you're executing and the code you're showing us?  You should pass the name of the FIFO to `configure_pipe()` as an argument; that gives you a more flexible function.  (I'd argue for `configure_fifo()` as the function name too; pipes exist too, and they're not the same as a FIFO.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks Jonathan. Yes, I have only picked up the relevant part and showed here. The whole code and logic are not  really concern.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for your suggestions. As I said, I wanted to the reader to be executed with `root` privileges. I have not yet implemented error checking as well.

Answer (score 3):

> It is very weird that I can't seem to make this work.

Well, not really.  You have strange requirements and fragile assertions you try to go by.

> The reader process has to be blocking.

Noooo... Why would you make such a limitation? Consider

```
ssize_t blocking_read(fd, void *buf, size_t len)
{
    struct timeval  timeout;
    fd_set          fds;
    int             r;
    ssize_t         n;

    /* First, do a speculative read, just in case
       there is data already available. */
    n = read(fd, buf, len);
    if (n >= 0)
        return n;
    else
    if (n != -1) {
        /* Paranoid check, will never happen .*/
        errno = EIO;
        return -1;
    } else
    if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
        return -1;

    /* Wait for data to become available. */
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    while (1) {
        FD_SET(fd, &fds);
        timeout.tv_sec = 60; /* One minute */
        timeout.tv_usec = 0; /* and no millionths of seconds */

        r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (r < 0)
            return -1; /* errno set by select() */
        else
        if (!r)
            continue;  /* Timeout */

        n = read(fd, buf, len);
        if (n >= 0)
            return n;
        else
        if (n != -1) {
            /* Paranoid check, will never happen .*/
            errno = EIO;
            return -1;
        } else
        if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
            return -1;
    }
}
```

It acts like a blocking read on both blocking and nonblocking descriptors. It does wake up once per minute if nothing happens, but you can tune that until it is long enough to not matter. (I would consider values between one second and 86400 seconds, about one day. Any longer is just silliness. Remember it is a timeout, and not an ordinary sleep: any signal delivery or incoming data will immediately wake it up.)

With this, you can initially create the FIFO in 0400 mode (`r--------`), open it `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK` in the reader, then use e.g. `fchmod(fifofd, 0222)` to change its mode (0222 = `-w--w--w-`) to allow writers. None of this blocks. None of the writer attempts to open the FIFO will succeed until the reader is ready.

The reader does not open and close the FIFO; it just keeps calling `blocking_read()`.

If writers open the FIFO nonblocking write-only (`O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCKING`), they will fail with `errno = ENXIO` if there is no reader, or with `errno = EACCES` if the reader is running but not ready yet. When there is a reader, the writes will succeed unless the reader cannot keep up. (When the reader has its buffer full, writers will get an error with `errno = EAGAIN` or `errno = EWOULDBLOCK`.)

Writers can easily do a nonblocking write, with a customizable timeout to wait until writing becomes possible; it is a very similar function to `blocking_read()` above.

> I expect the bytes_read to be exactly the sizeof(Message_Struct_t) (24 bytes) because I setup my writer as atomic. 24 bytes is less than PIPE_BUF, therefore Linux assures that it is atomic as long as I don't exceed the size-limit of a pipe.

In optimal conditions, perhaps.

For example, if a nefarious user does e.g. `echo 1 > your_pipe` just when a writer is writing a message, you lose the message boundaries. The reader gets the two bytes (`1` and newline) and the initial part of the message, the next read gets the last two bytes of that message and the initial part of the next message, as long as there are writers writing into the socket as fast or faster than the reader can read.

Because pipes and FIFOs never preserve message boundaries, your approach is extremely fragile. A better approach would be to use a datagram socket that does preserve message boundaries.

> I am no way exceeding the size-limit. My writer programs are like clients; they come, execute and terminate. So the writing side of the pipe is not always open.

You could easily exceed the size limit.

There is just the one pipe buffer, and it can become full (and therefore nonblocking writes fail), if there are more writers than the reader can keep up.  It is easy to cause that to happen: for example, if the reader does *anything* with the data, using two concurrent writers (like a Bash `for ((;;)) ; do printf 'message' > fifo ; done`) *will* fill the buffer, and cause any nonblocking writers to fail with `errno = EAGAIN` or `errno = EWOULDBLOCK`.

This is not just theoretical; it is easy to prove using Bash and mknod in practice.

---

I have a feeling OP is constructing a disaster waiting to happen with their current mix of requirements, especially using a pipe (or FIFO) for datagram transfer.

Personally, I would use an [Unix domain datagram socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) bound to a pathname, probably `/var/run/yourservice`. This would guarantee message boundaries (two different messages will not be mixed, like they can with pipes or FIFOs).  Both the reader and writers could use [ancillary data](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) to pass an [SCM_CREDENTIALS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), which allows the reader to verify the user ID and group ID the writer used.

(The writer can choose between real or effective identities. The kernel always verifies the SCM_CREDENTIALS ancillary message fields, and will not allow incorrect data to be sent. In other words, the SCM_CREDENTIALS ancillary message fields will always be correct *at the moment the message was sent*.)

(Note that using a datagram protocol, the reader cannot verify the details of the process that sent the message, because by the time the reader receives the SCM_CREDENTIALS ancillary message, the original sender could have executed another process, or exited with the OS reusing the process ID for some other new process.  To verify which executable was used to send a message, one would need a connection-oriented protocol, like Unix domain stream socket, with the writer sending two or three messages, all with the same SCM_CREDENTIALS ancillary message.  This is quite tricky to do correctly, so most programmers consider such verification icky.)

Comment: I would be willing to show a practical reader-writers example using Unix domain datagram sockets, but unfortunately that would not answer the stated or even the underlying problem.  In my opinion, OP has driven themselves to a corner with conflicting requirements, and the correct solution is to restart form the most important requirements, without any extraneous restrictions on the solution itself. That is, describing the desired behaviour, with zero consideration as to how to implement it.

Comment: Tried your blocking_read code (thank you for providing it!). I think you have an extra NULL parameter to "select", and need an "int" before fd in the function parameters - at least for me, it does not compile without these changes.